# Load GIF as background in linear layout through Glide

Tags: android, gif, android-glide

I have to set a GIF image as background in a linear layout. I am using below code

```
final LinearLayout layoutMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.game_screen_background)
     .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
         @Override
         public void onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
             layoutMain.setBackground(resource);
         }
     });
```

But its not setting GIF as background. GIF is in raw folder and I am using below glide dependency

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
```

Why is the GIF not loading? Am I missing something?

Comment: did you debugged your code ?. Maybe it is throwing some exception/error. ?

Comment: no its coming to onResourceReady but not setting background to linear layout

Answer (score 0):

I think `final` may be cause the problem. You may remove it and try like this way. and You are missing like `asGif()`. 
You can load an image in a LinearLayout like this. I'm just showing you the hard part which is setting an image to the background.

**For Glide version before 4.X**

If the source you provide is not a Gif, and maybe just a regular image, there is no way of registering that issue. Glide accepts Gifs or images as the load() parameter. If you, the developer, expect that the URL is a Gif, which is not the case, Glide can't automatically detect that. Thus, they introduced an additional method to force Glide into expecting a Gif **asGif()** and you can call **asBitmap()** to guarantee the display as a regular image.

As per this document https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-displaying-gifs-and-videos

**Like :**
**For Glide version before 4.X**

```
LinearLayout layoutMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);


    Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.game_screen_background)
            .asGif()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                    layoutMain.setBackground(resource);
                }
            });
```

**Update for Gide v4 onward:**

```
LinearLayout layoutMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
GlideApp.with(this).load(R.drawable.backgroundimage).into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    layoutMain.setBackground(resource);
                }
            }
        });
```